# Scraping .aspx site after click

Tags: python, asp.net, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am attempting to scrape scheduling data for my squadron from:
https://www.cnatra.navy.mil/scheds/schedule_data.aspx?sq=vt-9

I have figured out how to extract the data using BeautifulSoup using:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import bs4 as bs

url = 'https://www.cnatra.navy.mil/scheds/schedule_data.aspx?sq=vt-9'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table')
print(table.text)
```

However, the table is hidden under the date is selected (if other than the current day) and the 'View Schedule' button is pressed.

How can I modify my code to 'press' the 'View Schedule' button so I can then scrape the data? Bonus points if the code can also choose a date!

I attempted to use:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/users/base/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.cnatra.navy.mil/scheds/schedule_data.aspx?sq=vt-9")
button = driver.find_element_by_id('btnViewSched')
button.click()
```

which successfully opens Chrome and 'clicks' the button, but I can't scrape from this as the address is unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pure `selenium` to get the schedule:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.cnatra.navy.mil/scheds/schedule_data.aspx?sq=vt-9")
button = driver.find_element_by_id('btnViewSched')
button.click()
print(driver.find_element_by_id('dgEvents').text)
```

Output:

```
TYPE VT Brief EDT RTB Instructor Student Event Hrs Remarks Location
Flight VT-9 07:45 09:45 11:15 JARVIS, GRANT M [LT] LENNOX, KEVIN I [ENS] BI4101 1.5 2 HR BRIEF MASS BRIEF  
Flight VT-9 07:45 09:45 11:15 MOYNAHAN, WILLIAM P [CDR] FINNERAN, MATTHEW P [1stLt] BI4101 1.5 2 HR BRIEF MASS BRIEF  
Flight VT-9 07:45 12:15 13:45 JARVIS, GRANT M [LT] TAYLOR, ADAM R [1stLt] BI4101 1.5 2 HR BRIEF MASS BRIEF @ 0745 W/ JARVIS MEI OPS  
Flight VT-9 07:45 12:15 13:45 MOYNAHAN, WILLIAM P [CDR] LOW, TRENTON G [ENS] BI4101 1.5 2 HR BRIEF MASS BRIEF @ 0745 W/ MOYNAHAN MEI OPS  
Watch VT-9   00:00 14:00 ANDERSON, LAURA [LT]   ODO (ON CALL) 14.0    
Watch VT-9   00:00 14:00 ANDERSON, LAURA [LT]   ODO (ON CALL) 14.0    
Watch VT-9   00:00 23:59 ANDERSON, LAURA [LT]   ODO (ON CALL) 24.0    
Watch VT-9   00:00 23:59 ANDERSON, LAURA [LT]   ODO (ON CALL) 24.0    
Watch VT-9   07:00 19:00   STUY, JOHN [LTJG] DAY IWO 12.0    
Watch VT-9   19:00 07:00   STRACHAN, ALLYSON [LTJG] IWO 12.0
```

Comment: @exos what is "faux chrome"?

Answer (score 1):

As I read your problem,  you need to use selenium for scraping .aspx pages where input required.

Read this article it will help you  to [scrape data for .aspx page with selenium](https://medium.com/@emery_44439/data-scraping-pdf-parsing-python-bot-15b97bb37785)

Answer (score -1):

On "View Schedule" click, request with same url but with data `btnViewSched=View Schedule` and tokens are send. Here code, that collect table data in list of maps format:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,'
              'application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7',
}
response = requests.get('https://www.cnatra.navy.mil/scheds/schedule_data.aspx?sq=vt-9', headers=headers)
assert response.ok

page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
# get __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR for further requests
__VIEWSTATE = page.find("input", attrs={"id": "__VIEWSTATE"}).attrs["value"]
__EVENTVALIDATION = page.find("input", attrs={"id": "__EVENTVALIDATION"}).attrs["value"]
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = page.find("input", attrs={"id": "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"}).attrs["value"]

# View Schedule click set here
data = {
  '__EVENTTARGET': '',
  '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
  '__VIEWSTATE': __VIEWSTATE,
  '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
  '__EVENTVALIDATION': __EVENTVALIDATION,
  'btnViewSched': 'View Schedule',
  'txtNameSearch': ''
}
# request with params
response = requests.post('https://www.cnatra.navy.mil/scheds/schedule_data.aspx?sq=vt-9', headers=headers, data=data)
assert response.ok

page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
# get table headers to map as a keys in result
table_headers = [td.text.strip() for td in page.select("#dgEvents tr:first-child td")]
# get all rows, without table headers
table_rows = page.select("#dgEvents tr:not(:first-child)")

result = []
for row in table_rows:
    table_columns = row.find_all("td")

    # use map with results for row and add all columns as map (key:value)
    row_result = {}
    for i in range(0, len(table_headers)):
        row_result[table_headers[i]] = table_columns[i].text.strip()

    # add row_result to result list
    result.append(row_result)

for r in result:
    print(r)

print("the end")
```

Example output:

> {'TYPE': 'Flight', 'VT': 'VT-9', 'Brief': '07:45', 'EDT': '09:45', 'RTB': '11:15', 'Instructor': 'JARVIS, GRANT M [LT]', 'Student': 'LENNOX, KEVIN I [ENS]', 'Event': 'BI4101', 'Hrs': '1.5', 'Remarks': '2 HR BRIEF MASS BRIEF', 'Location': ''}